# How can I let my audience tag my posts?

Tags: tags

I have over 400 interviews on my site and my audience keeps asking me for a way to sort through them.

I don't have time to tag all 400 interviews. Do you think there's a way for my audience to tag interviews themselves?

Comment: How did the interviewee's submit the interview ?  Did they register to your wordpress site and add it as a post ? or did you manually add them to your site via wp-admin ?

Comment: Andrew, wasn't @Chis_O answer useful? . . . Chris, btw, congrats on the ten thousand, cheers..!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Andrew,

Matt Mullenweg uses a similar feature on on his blog, [Ma.tt](http://ma.tt), that lets users tag photos.

[image]

He released the code as a plugin, [Matts Community Tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/matts-community-tags/).  You will have to create a custom taxonomy for the tags and add some additional code to your templates to make it work.  See the [discussion on the WordPress.org forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/matts-community-tags-installation-instructions?replies=32) for more information.